# problema con esta consulta mysql usando el ORM sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, sequelize

Tengo horas tratando de hacer funcionar esta consulta y no logro que funcione correctamente. En el backend recibo varios parámetros, la consulta funciona cuando recibo algunos parametros, pero por ejemplo cuándo recibo solo la categoría, por ejemplo, no retorna nada, la consulta que hace es esta:

```
Executing (default): 
SELECT `id_productos`, `status`, `nombre_producto`, `medida_producto`, `unidad_producto`, `imagenes_producto`, `informacion_nutricional`, `descripcion_corta`, `descripcion_extendida`, `especificaciones`, `precio`, `precio_oferta`, `oferta`, `destacado`, `borrado`, `cantidad`, `filtro_1`, `filtro_2`, `filtro_3`, `etiqueta_1`, `etiqueta_2`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `marcaIdMarca`, `usuarioIdUsuarios`, `regionClIdRe`, `provinciaClIdPr`, `comunaClIdCo`, `categoriaIdCategorias`, `subcategoriaIdSubcategorias` 
FROM `productos` AS `productos` 
WHERE 0 = 1 AND `productos`.`categoriaIdCategorias` = 1 AND `productos`.`status` = 1;
```

No entiendo ese `WHERE 0 = 1`, ahora si desde el front paso por ejemplo, la categoría con la subcategoria, ahí si obtengo resultados y la consulta que se genera es esta:

```
Executing (default): 
SELECT `id_productos`, `status`, `nombre_producto`, `medida_producto`, `unidad_producto`, `imagenes_producto`, `informacion_nutricional`, `descripcion_corta`, `descripcion_extendida`, `especificaciones`, `precio`, `precio_oferta`, `oferta`, `destacado`, `borrado`, `cantidad`, `filtro_1`, `filtro_2`, `filtro_3`, `etiqueta_1`, `etiqueta_2`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `marcaIdMarca`, `usuarioIdUsuarios`, `regionClIdRe`, `provinciaClIdPr`, `comunaClIdCo`, `categoriaIdCategorias`, `subcategoriaIdSubcategorias` FROM `productos` AS `productos` 
WHERE ((`productos`.`filtro_1` = 1) OR (`productos`.`filtro_2` = 1)) AND `productos`.`categoriaIdCategorias` = 1 AND `productos`.`status` = 1 AND (`productos`.`subcategoriaIdSubcategorias` = 1);
```

Por que me sucede esto? Que estoy haciendo Mal? Quisiera que si solo paso la categoría, pues me retorne los datos correspondientes, si paso los demás parámetros igual retorne los resultados correspondientes a esos parámetros.

Si sirve de algo aquí está el modelo de la tabla:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Productos = sequelize.define('productos', {
    id_productos: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    // ESTADO DE APROBACIÓN DEL PRODUCTO
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    nombre_producto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    medida_producto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    unidad_producto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    imagenes_producto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    informacion_nutricional: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    descripcion_corta: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    descripcion_extendida: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    especificaciones: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    precio: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    precio_oferta: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    oferta: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    destacado: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    //Si borrado es 1 , el producto fue borrado 
    borrado: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    cantidad: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    // FLTROS DE BUSQUEDA
    filtro_1: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    filtro_2: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    filtro_3: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    // ETIQUETAS
    etiqueta_1: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

    etiqueta_2: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });
  Productos.associate = (models) => {
    Productos.belongsTo(models.marcas);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.usuarios);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.region_cl);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.provincia_cl);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.comuna_cl);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.categorias);
    Productos.belongsTo(models.subcategorias);
  };
  return Productos;
}
```

y la consulta que estoy haciendo es la siguiente:

```
const productos = await db.productos.findAll({
  where: {
    categoriaIdCategorias: id_categoria,
    status: 1,
    marcaIdMarca: {
      [Op.or]: arregloIdMarcas
    },
    subcategoriaIdSubcategorias: {
      [Op.or]: arregloDeSubCategorias
    },
    [Op.or]: [{
        filtro_1: {
          [Op.or]: arregloIdFiltros
        }
      },
      {
        filtro_2: {
          [Op.or]: arregloIdFiltros
        }
      }

    ]
  }
});
```

Estoy usando angular y node.js con sequelize en el back.